# PEP508: why either version requirement or URL but not both?

Tags: python, pip, pep

When configuring `install_requires=[...]` in a `setup.py` file, we can specify either version numbers:

```
package >= 1.2.3
```

or a source:

```
package @ git+https://git.example.com/some/path/to/package@master#egg=package
```

But I did not manager to specify both, I got an error for everything I tried.

Looking at the [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/), it looks like it is intended:

```
specification = wsp* ( url_req | name_req ) wsp*
```

where `wsp*` just means optional whitespace.

1. Did I get it correctly that it is not possible to write something like this?
   `package >= 1.2.3 @ git+https://...`
2. What is the reason for this decision?

Comment: Because a URL is by definition "a specific artifact to install". You get whatever that points to, so adding further constraints makes no sense.

Comment: I think it makes sense as a safety measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because getting a python package from a URL/Github does not have a way to get historical builds/packages like you would via packages stored via [PyPi](https://pypi.org/).

Github/URLs references a single snapshot of code, you could sort of simulate getting specific versions if you have tags or release branches in GitHub and update the URL to reference those versions:

`git+https://git.example.com/some/path/to/package@master#egg=package`
`git+https://git.example.com/some/path/to/package@develop#egg=package`
`git+https://git.example.com/some/path/to/package@1.4.2#egg=package`

Comment: the PEP actually mentions that URLs are "a specific artifact to install", whether it's VCS or HTTP you get what's at that URL and that's it.

Comment: It is difficult to verify an answer based on a speculation. I appreciate it anyway.

Comment: I agree but I didn't have a chance to do the proper look ups but it appears that Masklinn confirmed so i'll take the speculation comment out of the answer