# python and pip: dependency is never upgraded with PEP508 URL requrements

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

PEP508 allows specifying a URL for a dependency, in particular a VCS.  This is most useful for private packages that are not on pypi.  If I have a package whose setup.py looks like:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='foo',
      install_requires=['bar @ git+ssh://git@github.com/me/bar@1.2.3']
)
```

Then when I say `pip install foo`, it will download and install `bar` from the github repo. But if I later want to install a new version of `foo`, (`pip install --upgrade foo`), which has an updated `bar` dependency (e.g. tag 2.3.4), pip says that the dependency is already satisfied.

Is there a way to encode version information or something that will force pip to recognize that the dependency is NOT being met?  I know I can give pip the  `--upgrade-strategy eager` option, but that would affect ALL dependencies recursively and is too heavy-handed.

This related question [PEP508: why either version requirement or URL but not both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847772/pep508-why-either-version-requirement-or-url-but-not-both) asks about not being able to specify a version, but doesn't answer why pip doesn't get the URL when asked to upgrade.

Comment: What does `pip install --upgrade foo` do?

Comment: @JohnGordon I should have been more clear, the failure to upgrade the dependency happens when I call `install --upgrade foo`. Edited

Comment: VCS dependencies are not upgraded automatically as it's impossible to query a list of available versions from a git repo in a reliable way, so this is simply not implemented.