# Python Setup.py - dependency as url to TAR or GIT

Tags: python, dependencies, setuptools, setup.py

accordingly to my research the following should work:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages
...
REQUIRES_INSTALL = [
    'spacy==2.3.2',
    'tensorflow==1.14.0',
    'Keras==2.2.4',
    'keras-contrib@git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git#egg=keras-contrib',
    'en-core-web-sm@https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0.tar.gz#egg=en-core-web-sm'
]
...
setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    install_requires=REQUIRES_INSTALL,
    ...
)
```

When building a wheel or egg, everything is fine: `python setup.py bdist_wheel`.

But when trying to install the package (whl or egg) with `pip install -U dist/mypack-....whl`.

I get:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras-contrib (from mypack==0.3.5) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for keras-contrib (from mypack==0.3.5)
...
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement en-core-web-sm (from mypack==0.3.5) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for en-core-web-sm (from mypack==0.3.5)
```

I have tried to same via `setup.cfg` but still no luck.

---

As reference - all these dependency are working when installing them first from `requirments.txt` and then installing the wheel.

```
spacy==2.3.2
tensorflow==1.14.0
Keras==2.2.4
keras-contrib@git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git#egg=keras-contrib
en-core-web-sm@https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0.tar.gz#egg=en-core-web-sm
```

```sh
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -U dist/mypack-....whl
```

But this is not *clean* way, since a wheel should be self contained.

Thank you for any hint!

---

**Environment**

- Python: 3.7.0
- Pip: 20.2.4
- setuptools: 50.3.2

Answer (score 5):

Some time ago it was possible to define a single `requirements.txt` or similar containing both specs for PyPI packages and links to repositories and archives.

That demanded to parse the `requirements.txt` and split them into "requirements" and "dependencies", where "requirements" would contain definitions of PyPI packages and "dependencies" — links.

Setuptools has different args for `setup()` for these: [`install_requires`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html?highlight=install_requires#id4) and [`dependency_links`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html?highlight=dependency_links#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi).

And it really worked: one was able to define a `requirements.txt` and install a package both as `python setup.py install` and as `pip install .`. Moreover, it was possible to install just dependencies via `pip install -r requirements.txt`. All ways worked and allowed to have a single place to define all requirements including non-PyPI links.

However, support of `dependency_links` arg was dropped by `pip` since v19. And here's the weird part: it is not dropped by `setuptools`. But there's more.

As of today, `pip`:

- Supports only `install_requires`.
- Prefers PEP 508 notation for dependencies in definitions of packages (`install_requires`) and standalone `requirements.txt` or similar.
- Aborts installation of packages, which contain links in their `install_requires`.

Your definitions of dependencies mix 2 notations: prefixes like `keras-contrib@` are from PEP 508 and `#egg=` parts are from `setuptools` links notation.

This is not an issue: `pip` will ignore "eggs" as names are already defined before `@`.

I believe the installation of the package via `pip` works fine, i.e.:

```sh
  pip install .
```

However, the issues will arise if the package is installed via `setuptools`, i.e.:

```sh
  python setup.py install
```

`setuptools` does not understand PEP 508 notation and ignores links in `install_requires`. As of today, to make `setuptools` following links, both `install_requires` and `dependency_links` have to be used, e.g.:

```py
setup(
   ...
   install_requires=[
      ...
      "keras_contrib==2.0.8",
      ...
   ],
   dependency_links=[
      "https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/tarball/master#egg=keras_contrib-2.0.8",
      ...
   ],
)
```

Here are several tricky points:

- A single dependency is defined in 2 places: a package name in `install_requires` and a link in `dependency_links` to resolve the package dependency.
- The link is not `git+https://.../....git`, but it's a link to an archive: `https://.../tarball/...`.
- Egg name is in `snake_case`, not in `dash-case`. While it's possible to use `dash-case`, this will not allow specifying the version.
- Version in `install_requires` is delimited via `==` and in `dependency_links` — via `-`.
- It's possible to omit the version. But the only viable use case for that is if the package is not present in PyPI and is rarely updated. If the package is present in PyPI, but an unpublished version is needed, then the version must be specified.

And here's the bummer: fixing links for `setuptools` will break `pip`, as PEP 508 does not allow to specify versions. Keeping `keras-contrib==x.y.z @ ...` in `install_requires` will make `pip` to search for the package `keras-contrib==x.y.z`, where `==x.y.z` is not a version, but a part of the name. At the same time, not specifying a version will make `setuptools` to grab the latest version available at PyPI, not at the link from `dependency_links`.

In your case neither `keras-contrib` nor `en-core-web-sm` are present at PyPI, so using `keras_contrib@git+https://...` + `dependency_links` without version specified might work.

Otherwise, stick to `pip install .` and avoid using `python setup.py install` if the package depends on links.

See also:

- [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/)
- [PEP508: why either version requirement or URL but not both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847772/pep508-why-either-version-requirement-or-url-but-not-both)
- [How can I make setuptools install a package that's not on PyPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi)
- [pip install dependency links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061610/pip-install-dependency-links)
- [pip3 setup.py install_requires PEP 508 git URL for private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385900/pip3-setup-py-install-requires-pep-508-git-url-for-private-repo)
- [Why is dependency links in setup.py deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320277/why-is-dependency-links-in-setup-py-deprecated)
- [Changing PEP 508 URLs in setup.py doesn't reinstall the dependency](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6160)
- [Updating remote links with new URLs for PEP508 functionality](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5780)
- [Requirements using PEP 508 direct references ignore the URL](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/787)
- [Suggest alternatives for --process-dependency-links](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6162)
- [Un-deprecate `--process-dependency-links` until an alternative is implemented](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4187)
- [Changes to the pip dependency resolver in 20.3 (2020)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#changes-to-the-pip-dependency-resolver-in-20-2-2020)

> Trivia: several issues on GitHub are still open and PEP 508 is still in `Active` state since 2015. Digging around source code would reveal that [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a wrapper around Python's [distutils](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/introduction.html). `setuptools` is not a part of Python's stdlib, but the docs of `distutils` imply stdlib docs will be removed after docs of `setuptools` will be updated. At the same time `pip` is already bundled with Python's installations as Python's module. And yet we have [`pipfile`s](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile), [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), [`poetry`](https://python-poetry.org/), [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html), [`pipx`](https://pipxproject.github.io/pipx/), [`pip-tools`](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/), [`shiv`](https://shiv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [`spack`](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and the rest. Looks a bit overwhelming.